# java loading game page in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make loading page for a game which consist of a JFrame.I just want that loading page to open 3 seconds and after that time it will dispose and another frame will open i am using thread.sleep function just to wait load page but it won't work i don't know why? :(
here is my code

```
enter code here

new load();
   try 
   {
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       dispose();
       new gameInfo();

   } 
   catch (InterruptedException ex) 
   {
       Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

plz help

Comment: Maybe you try a SplashScreen as a solution? [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

Comment: You can try by new gameInfo().setVisible(true);

Comment: i did but the main problem is that by this code new load() page is  open after 3 sec but i want to it to dispose after 3 sec not open